# In Tableau: Count entries Column B that have the same value in Column A

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with two columns. For simplicity, lets say Column A is General Contractors and Column B is subcontractors.  Any given general contractor can have a variable number of subcontractors.     I would like to add a third column that simply displays a count of how many subcontractors each contractor has.

I have tried several calculations using "fixed" and "include" functions as well as "Count" and "CountD"  functions and have tried directly using the count functions (right-click>>measure>>count) but all I get are 1's in the resulting column.

The data come from a table where there is one row for each subcontractor, so the if a general contractor had 5 subcontractors then there would be 5 rows where the general contractor repeats it self over and over with a different subcontractor next to it.

There are far too many different general contractors to use conditional statements.

Is what I'm doing possible and what other things should I try?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{Fixed [general contractor]: Countd([sub contractor]) }
```

Add this field to your view after contractor and sub-contractor, you'll get that variable count say 5 repeated in each row that general contractor.

Comment: This is correct. I will add that if you wish to use the LOD measure for [subcontractor count], change to MAX() rather than SUM(). It will show 5 instead of 25 (5 rows each displaying 5 for [subcontractor count])